# How to authenticate to a ec2 instance using ubuntu 14.4

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

[image]

I want to use a standalone ssh client to connect to my ec2 instance. I've come across https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/firessh/ which looks like a good idea in that I can just add a connection to the browser instead of outside programs. However I can't get connected following the amazon.com instructions in the screenshot.

[image]

I have set up a ubuntu 14.4 LTS instance as above I've followed the instructions in the top screenshot , trying to apply them to a GUI but it keeps saying:

```
connected .... authentication failed.
```

How can I get this working?

[image]

edit: after changing 'account name' to ubuntu;

[image]

Comment: Try the username `admin`

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the account name to `ubuntu`